# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar mi app en apple store?

Tags: swift, xcode, iphone, certificado-apple

He subido exitosamente mi aplicación a Apple Store, pero tengo un nueva versión, ¿Cómo puedo realizar la actualización?, debo borrarla y subirla nuevamente ?

Gracias.

Comment: Este video te puede ser muy útil paso por paso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kggtfVoQwIo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para actualizar la aplicación en App Store deben tener primero aprobado la aplicación por parte de Apple. Una vez la tengas aprobada se debe crear una nueva version dentro de App Store Connect (en la opción +VERSION O PLATAFORMA). Luego subir la nueva version para distribución a testflight, seleccionarla y mandar a revisar.

Answer (score 0):

No, simplemente creas una nueva version en el appstore, y le pones al nuevo build el id de version, lo subes y si tienes automatico la publicacion de la nueva versión, se publicara de lo contrario, le das enviar para revision y listo cunado la revisen y la aprueben estara lista la nueva version.